# How to parse json array if it is the first thing in response in java?

Tags: java, json, parsing

```
[
  {
    "product_id": "1",
    "product_name": "Coke",
    "product_details": "1.5 liter"
  },
  {
    "product_id": "2",
    "product_name": "Nestle",
    "product_details": "1 Liter"
  },
  {
    "product_id": "3",
    "product_name": "Nestle",
    "product_details": "1 Liter"
  }
]
```

This is the response I am getting, as it is not in the form of object and as it is the first thing in my response it doent have a key. How can i parse it in java?

Comment: what are you using to make the request?

Comment: Depends on what library you're using to unmarshal objects, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48192101/unmarshal-a-json-array-in-a-json-list) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use [JSONArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray#JSONArray(java.lang.String))

```
String response = *your response string*
JSONArray myJSONArray = JSONArray(response);
```